# Of thumbnails and folder permissions

Tags: errors, post-thumbnails, permissions

I am trying to make TimThumb work on my domain. After having tried and tested every step on this [troubleshooting guide](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/tip-for-timthumb-thumb-php-not-generating-thumbnails), it finally came down to folder permissions. The thumbnail cache is owned by my `accountname`, while the processes trying to access the folder (i.e. WordPress) are `nobody`. The solution suggested by the author of the linked post is to `chown` the folder to nobody.

What are the implications of this? Will it affect how WordPress works or my FTP?

Answer (score 1):

One problem if you change the ownership of the directory is that maybe (depending on the permissions) you won't be able to modify anything in it. You can do two things to give `nobody` access to this folder: either you `chown` the folder to `nobody`, as suggested, but you can also change the file mode (access control) of the directory with `chmod` so that anyone (including `nobody`) can write in it. If you have even more control over your server you could create a group that includes you and `nobody`, and give this group access to write in the directory.

The `chmod` method is used most often, as it works with most hosts. Check your `wp-config/uploads/` directory, probably everyone has read and write permissions there too.